# "There is no deep copy in java," but does it matter for list of Strings?

Tags: java

Let's say I do:

```
public List<E> gimmeAList(List<E> original) {
    return new ArrayList<E>(original); // this is a shallow memcopy.
}
```

I try to modify the new list, but since Strings (or any immutable object) are immutable, doing  something like: `gimmeAList(something).get(0).replace("a", "b");` doesn't ACTUALLY seem to change anything in either lists.

So in this case, am I allowed to just assume (for immutable objects in a list) that `new ArrayList<E>(original)` is guaranteed to be, for all intents and purposes, basically a deep copy?

Comment: I've fixed your capitalization for you.  In the future, please do this yourself; it's unfair to expect the community to always fix up your questions, and we do expect questions to be reasonably capitalization and punctuation complete (the audience for your question being the entire Internet, not just the locals).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you. I have a combination of laziness and dyslexia :'(

Comment: A decent spelling/grammar checker should be able to pick up the capitalization problems.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, absolutely - copying a collection of immutable objects is *effectively* deep, unless you do something crazy like synchronizing on the references or comparing them for reference equality (i.e. operations which depend on object identity).

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but i believe `new ArrayList<E>(original)` uses Java Native Code `System arraycopy`, which is a constant time operation. so are you basically saying that the function `gimmeAList` is a constant time operation of a deep copy?

Comment: @DavidT.: No, it's not constant time. It's linear, because System.arraycopy is linear.

Comment: @DavidT This only applies for immutable types.

Answer (score 1):

Copies of immutable objects are practically (or effectively) deep. However, it matters if the type `E` is mutable. But if it were so, you could call `clone()` on each Cloneable `E` and then you have a "deep copy". I believe your original premise "there is no deep copy in java" is incorrect, assuming you meant there is no way to create a "deep copy".

Comment: yup. it definitely depends on the definition of "deep copy"

Answer (score 1):

Object references in Java may be used to encapsulate identity, mutable state, both, or neither, in addition to encapsulating immutable aspects of state other than identity.  Making a proper copy of an object which contains references to other objects requires knowing what is encapsulated by those references.  Assuming `foo` is an object with reference-type field `bar`, and `fooCopy` is supposed to be a copy of `foo`...

- If `foo.bar` is used to encapsulate the identity of an object, but not mutable state, then `fooCopy.bar` should identify the same object.
- If `foo.bar` is used to encapsulate an object's mutable state, but not its identity, then `fooCopy.bar` should identify a newly-constructed copy of the object identified by `foo.bar`.
- If `foo.bar` is used to encapsulate both identity and mutable state, then it will generally not be possible to make a proper copy of `foo` in isolation.  If `foo` is part of a large forest of interconnected objects, it may be possible to construct a new forest of objects whose interconnections are isomorphic to those of the original, and have `fooCopy.bar` identify the object within that forest that corresponds to `foo.bar`'s place in the original, but that's not apt to be simple.
- If `foo.bar` encapsulates neither identity nor mutable state, then `fooCopy.bar` may legitimately identify *either* the same object as `foo.bar`, or a legitimate copy of the object identified by `foo.bar`.

Since string references are generally used to encapsulate neither identity nor mutable state, the last scenario applies; one may either copy the string reference or store a reference to a new copy the underlying string, whichever is more convenient.